# In Statistics, Does a Missed Shot While Being Fouled Still Count as a Missed Shot?

Tags: basketball, statistics

During a game, players get fouled a lot, and they often throw up a shot, to try to have an opportunity to get more points. When you throw up a shot while fouled, in your game statistics, does it count as a missed shot, or do they only count it if you make it because you were fouled? Is there a more common way of counting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not, it is simply a free shot, and why a lot of guys who drive to the basket a lot not only shoot foul shots but have a higher shooting percentage.  If you miss it is simply a mention of fouled while shooting (no base stat - yes understand this is an advanced stat) and then if they make it it is a shot attempt and a shot made. This is how it is scored period, no matter what age or level you are playing.

Comment: Does it count as a make or nothing? If I get fouled and miss, am I shooting 1/1 or 0/0?

Comment: You are 0/0 if you miss and 1/1 if you make it.